# How to Store Form's.html Profile picture from upload.php page, how can i take image in another upload.php page to be stored in database?

Tags: php, mysql

i have have `form.php` (`enctype="multipart/form-data"`) page and i want to (`method =` ) post image to `upload.php` in blob.

How to handle Image in `upload.php` as i handle (`input type =`) text as    `$_POST['username']` to be stored in database?

Comment: There are dozens of tutorials out there on uploading files to mysq.

Comment: @Shadow ,,, yes you are right but all tutorials teach to handle the image on the same page... but i want to handle that image in another page name as upload.php

Comment: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Shadow i want to redirect the image data on upload.php and after that i want to store that image which was earlier uploaded on form.html and (method = ) post on upload.php

Comment: Weĺl, good luck with that. The point of SO is to **help** you in solving your problem, not to do your work from scratch instead of you. Pls share what you have tried so far and where you got stuck with it and you will get help.

Comment: @Shadow As you send form.html data using post method like (input type= "text" name="un") "Name" and (input type = "Password" name="psw") "User Password" to upload.php file then on upload.php file you write code to $name = $_POST['un']; $_POST[psw]; to handle the fetch the data,,, similarly i wand to handle Image on upload.php as BLOB to store on the database...

Comment: @ShivanshChaudhri you better edit your question with with code, it will be easier to read and help you

Comment: Please do not write big lumps of code in comments. If they are relevant to the question then [edit] them into the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you upload an image in form as

```
<form action="upload2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="featured_image" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

...you can use its data on upload2.php with using global variable $_FILES as

```
print_r($_FILES(['featured_image']));
```

$_FILES(['featured_image']) is an array that stores error,tmp_name,size etc..Uploaded files are temporarily stored im tmp folder in xammp ..Using move_uploaded_file() you should save file from tmp folder to desired  folder path..and the filename should be saved on database...So practically the image is not saved in database ..but only filename is saved as text field on database..

Comment: By using BLOB data type you can store image in binary form

Comment: @Shivansh Chaudhri I wasn't mentioning that image can't be saved in database ..The point is you can't afford to store image on database in terms of space complexity...Just being practical..

Comment: IMAGE can be saved in database in BLOB form, its another matter that it will more costly.